# Apptentive for android crashing on message center

Tags: android, apptentive

I've added Apptentive to my Android app [following the instructions here](http://www.apptentive.com/docs/android/integration/).

I initially see the message center, and when I send a message to my support team, everything seems fine.  When the support team responds, I see the response in the message center.

However, when I close the message center and re-open the message center on the app, Apptentive crashes with this stack trace:

```
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp, PID: 30311
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.apptentive.android.sdk.module.messagecenter.view.holder.IncomingTextMessageHolder.updateMessage(IncomingTextMessageHolder.java:44)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.apptentive.android.sdk.module.messagecenter.view.MessageAdapter.getView(MessageAdapter.java:314)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-20 17:12:42.256 30311-30311/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:  at com.andro
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since Apptentive is working, until it tries to load the message center with a populated response.

Comment: Hey @styler1972, I work at Apptentive and wanted to note here on SO that we're looking into this. It sounds like we connected via email, but when we figure it out we can post an answer here if it's helpful for other devs.

Comment: Great! I rolled back to 1.7.5 for now. Thanks